# Java regex negative lookahead to replace non-triple characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to take a number, convert it into a string and replace all characters that are not a triple.

Eg. if I pass in `1222331` my replace method should return `222`. I can find that this pattern exists but I need to get the value and save it into a string for additional logic. I don't want to do a for loop to iterate through this string.

I have the following code:

```
String first = Integer.toString(num1);
String x = first.replaceAll("^((?!([0-9])\\3{2})).*$","");
```

But it's replacing the triple digits also. I only need it to replace the rest of the  characters. Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Maybe `first = first.replaceAll("((\\d)\\2{2})|\\d", "$1");`?

Comment: @jorge Campos that one didn't work since it was just returning 3 numbers in a row.

Comment: @stribizhev that one worked! Thanks much. I should have used a strict capture instead of using negative lookahead

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer with some clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
first = first.replaceAll("((\\d)\\2{2})|\\d", "$1");
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJ9xP5/1)

The regex - `((\d)\2{2})|\d` - matches either a digit that repeats thrice (and captures it into Group 1), or just matches any other digit. `$1` just restores the captured text in the resulting string while removing all others.

Comment: Is it working for you or do you need more clarification?